# Simple logic equivalence incorrect

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am having some problems negating a rather simple logical statement. I am currently taking a introduction course, so please bear with me if my question is silly.

I am supposed to turn this:

$$ \lnot( p \lor q \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q \land r)) $$

Into:

$$ \lnot p \land \lnot q \land \lnot r $$

But I guess I am already some mistakes early in my simplification:

\begin{gather}
    \lnot p \land \lnot q \land \lnot(\lnot p \land \lnot q \land r) \\
    \lnot p \land \lnot q \land ( p \lor q \lor \lnot r) \\
    \mbox{?? No clue what to do now}
\end{gather}

Can someone spot where my train is off track?

Comment: What is the intended associativity in the first formula?  Is $\lnot p \lor \lnot q \land r$ supposed to be $(\lnot p \lor \lnot q) \land r$ or is it supposed to be $\lnot p \lor (\lnot q \land r)$?

Comment: And if it supposed to be $\lnot p\lor\lnot q\land r$ then the negation can't be $p\land q\land \lnot r$. I think it was meant to be $\lnot p\land\lnot q\land r$

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: The associativity provided is that the solutons tells me is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your work is fine up to the point you left off: So, good work!

Picking up where you left off, we have:

> ¬p ^ ¬q ^ (p v q v ¬r)

We can ***distribute*** the conjunction $(\lnot p \land \lnot q) \land...$ over the parentheses (a disjunction) $(p \lor q \lor \lnot r)$:

$$(\lnot p \land \lnot q \land p) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q \land q) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q \land \lnot r)$$

$$(\color{blue}{\bf (\lnot p \land p)}\land \lnot q) \lor (\lnot p \land \color{blue}{\bf (\lnot q \land q)}) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q \land \lnot r)$$

The first two terms form contradictions, and are hence false. You are left with $$\lnot p \land \lnot q \land \lnot r$$

To see how we can eliminate the first two terms in parentheses:

$$(\color{blue}{\bf (\lnot p \land p)}\land \lnot q) \lor (\lnot p \land \color{blue}{\bf (\lnot q \land q)}) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q \land \lnot r)$$

$$\equiv (\color{blue}{\bf F}\land \lnot q) \lor (\lnot p \land \color{blue}{\bf F}) \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q \land \lnot r)$$

$$\equiv F \lor F \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q \land \lnot r)$$

$$\equiv \lnot p \land \lnot q \land \lnot r$$

Comment: Excellent! This was just what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @amWhy: Excellent feedback and you are so good at these! =1